# mysql dynamic replace (like a case on the search)

Tags: mysql, replace, case

I have a situation where the `REPLACE` value to search for could be one of 2 scenarios - I want to find either one and replace with 1 value regardless of which scenario was found.

What I need syntax to simulate: `REPLACE(columnA, 'value1' OR 'value2', 'value3')`

Any ideas?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean? do you want to replace columnA with any of those three values? what is the criteria to choose one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So without knowing all of the details this wont be a complete answer until you clarify more.. but this is the general approach you can use

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN LOCATE('value1',columnA) > 0  -- # -- basically find your condition and replace with it or else replace with another condition
        THEN REPLACE (columnA, 'value1', 'value3')
        ELSE REPLACE(columnA, 'value2', 'value3')
    END
FROM ...
```

so you may want a different condition but from what I understood if value1 is inside columnA then you want to replace it with value 3 or else put in value 2..